# How to read a table from .txt file to C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to read a matrix from a file and use it in my program. but when I output the results, it shows that it is not reading correctly.
Here is the code:

```
#define I 5 
#define J 5 
#define P 2 

int i,j,k;  //for loops

int main ()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    double C[I][J];

    inFile.open("C.txt", ios::in);
    if (! inFile) {
        cerr << "unable to open file C.txt for reading" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<I; i++)
        for(j=0; j<J; j++)
            inFile >> C[i][j];

    outFile.open("results.txt");
    outFile<< "C" <<endl;
    for(i=0;i<I;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<J;j++)
            outFile<< C[i][j];
        outFile<< endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

C is a matrix of integer values 2 3 5... but what I get is

> 316-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061
>   -9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061 -9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061

Comment: Normally it would be handy to show us what your input is, what your output is and what you expected instead.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but where are `I` and `J` defined? Are you sure they are not both equal to 0?

Comment: Your example should not compile. It misses a `#define I` probably, etc.

Comment: What is `I` and `J`? What's `C.txt`? Just copy&&paste `main()` function is not enough.

Comment: sorry I missed that part. I have defined them:#define I 5
#define J 5
#define P 2
int i,j,k; //for loops

Comment: You must *never* use I/O operations without checking the return value and/or error state. That is, always say something like `if (instream  >> data) { /* ... */ } else { /* error, die */ }`. Don't even bother posting until your code has proper error checks in place.

Comment: C is a matrix of integer values 2 3 5... but what I get is 316-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061
-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061
-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061
-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061
-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061-9.25596e+061

Comment: Edit your question to contain the data. That way it's not hidden within a bunch of comments. You can always edit your question. :)

Comment: @Anna you should edit your question with extra information rather than adding it in a comment.

Comment: This is not the entire source file. Where are the `#include` directives? Please do not edit out parts of source if you can help it. Where is your "C.txt" file? Please post it as it is, from the very first to the very last byte.

Answer (score 3):

You should output a whitespace after each number, otherwise they will be all glued together.

```
outFile<< C[i][j] << " ";
```

You also should check your input for validity. Not showing it here (you already know how to check `if (! inFile)`).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are having problems with new lines, below modification will ignore new line character after reading each line:

```
for(i=0; i<I; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<J; j++)
        inFile >> C[i][j];
    inFile.ignore();  /// <<<--------
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are writing uninitialized variables to your output file, leading to undefined behavior.

I suspect your `C.txt` file does not contain the 5x5 matrix your program is looking for.

You should add a simple error check, e.g.:

```
for(i=0; i<I; i++)
    for(j=0; j<J; j++)
        if (!(inFile >> C[i][j])) { /* something's wrong here */ }
```