# how to read two txt files in c++

Tags: c++

I want to read two matrices from two different txt files, and say output them in another one.
I doesn't write all of them, it only writes the fist one and "Hi" and stops there.
So I believe it cannot read the second file.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define I 5
#define J 5
#define P 2
int i,j,k;  //for loops

int main ()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    double C[I][J];
    double u[I][J];
    double UB = 0;

    outFile.open("results.txt");
    // READ U0
    inFile.open("u.txt", ios::in);
    if (! inFile) {
        cerr << "unable to open file u.txt for reading" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < I; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < J; j++)
            inFile >> u[i][j];

    outFile << "u" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < I; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < J; j++)
            outFile << u[i][j];
            outFile << endl;
    }
    outFile << "Hi";

    //READ C
    inFile.open("C.txt", ios::in);
    if (! inFile) {
        cerr << "unable to open file C.txt for reading" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < I; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < J; j++)
            inFile >> C[i][j];
    outFile << "C" << endl;

    outFile << "UB=" << UB;


    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Vote to close: you can solve this (or at least isolate a more specific problem) by using the debugger.

Comment: Try closing "u.txt" before opening "C.txt". I haven't really done much with multiple files, but another method required me to close one before opening another.

Comment: how can I close that file? Thanks

Comment: `outFile << "Hi"; inFile.close(); inFile.open ("C.txt", ios::in);` You closed the other one at the end of main. I haven't simplified the inputs, but it isn't complaining about opening them.

Comment: You have already solved your [previous problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447787/how-to-read-a-table-from-txt-file-to-c)?

Comment: Awesome! that was the reason. Thanks so much Chris!

Comment: You are still not performing any error checking on your formatted input operations!

Comment: Yes Bart, but I didn't know how to close it. Actually this new code with the comment Chris just mentioned is the correct one.

Comment: I guess I'll make it into an answer so you can get the question closed. When posting, try to keep it as simple as possible. Instead of posting the matrices, simplify it to one number from each file. It narrows down what is working and what isn't and makes it easy to test ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two general choices:

- Use two different variables, such as `inFile1` and `inFile2`, for `u.txt` and `C.txt`.
- Close `inFile` with `inFile.close()` before trying to use the same variable to open a new file.